# Is retrofit slow in android?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using from `retrofit 2` in my app.My app good work with `wi-fi` but when I use from `Mobile data`,retrofit redirect me to `onFailure` method.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
```

Is `retrofit` slow ?

What can I do ?

Should I change my library to `volley` ?

In `onFailure` method get me this message :

```
failed to connect to /192.168.x.y (port 8087) after 10000 ms
```

Comment: Check [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-volley-vs-retrofit-better-approach/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with retrofit or okhttp. 
You are using a local network (assuming from the ip: 192.168.x.y) That will only be available on your wifi network, not on your mobile network that has (fortunately) no access to your wifi/local network.

Comment: Oh ,yes.I was not distracted. Thanks a lot for reminders.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a retrofit issue.
Check your local network.It may needs port number or others information.
Try to check on browser for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can not access local network (192.168.8.11) from mobile data. However you can access this network address using Wifi connection as you are connected to your local network using Wifi.

If you want to access your webservices from both ( mobile data & wifi ) then you need to broadcast them on live ip.

Wifi Connectivity allows you to access local webservices while mobile data only allows live available webservices.

Answer (score -1):

Retrofit not slow ...May be your server is slow 
 Please change socketTimeOut time on okHttp Config  to 1 minutes.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:3.x.x'
```

2 . Add this line :

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

3. Now set config :

```
  return new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
    .build();
```

Local ip not accessible from internet , run local server on port 80 and get main internet ip from ip websites like : https://www.whatismyip.com/ and connect to this ip .